# STRING_SPLIT skyrockets execution time of sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, split

For a SQL query I need to split an input string into its integer components and select values from a table according to the provided integers.

My problem: if there are a lot of integers (>300), the query gets slower and slower, i.e. for around 600 integers it uses more than one minute!

Here a small example of the executed query:

```sql
    DECLARE @inputStr VARCHAR(MAX) = '234,2344,12,523,5667,9825,345'

    SELECT
        surname,
        firstname
    FROM Addresses
    WHERE id IN (SELECT CAST(value AS INTEGER) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@inputStr, ',')))
```

Is there a known problem to this or any improvements I could do?

I'm glad for any help!

Comment: The best advice I can give you is not to mess around with delimited strings (if that's possible) and change the application + sql code to use table valued parameters instead.

Comment: Can you post the actual execution plan and table size/indexes of `Addresses`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probleme is that any explicit values in a "IN" operator is translate by a multiple OR in the WHERE clause by the algebrizer, before optimizing the query...
A great number of values in the IN operator will allways causes a lack of performances, whatever the manner to do it... !

By creating a temporay table, you will have another query execution plan that will boost your performances.

Si try this way :

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(value AS INTEGER) 
INTO   #T
FROM   STRING_SPLIT(@inputStr, ',');

SELECT surname,
       firstname
FROM   Addresses
WHERE  id IN (SELECT value 
              FROM   #T);
```

Eventually you can add a UNIQUE index to the temp table to increase performances :

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST("value" AS INTEGER) 
INTO   #T
FROM   STRING_SPLIT(@inputStr, ',');

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX X123456789 ON #T ("value");

SELECT surname,
       firstname
FROM   Addresses
WHERE  id IN (SELECT value 
              FROM   #T);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would move `STRING_SPLIT` to a `JOIN`, as it could well be that SQL Server is running `STRING_SPLIT` once for every row:

```sql
SELECT surname,
       firstname
FROM dbo.Addresses A
     JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@InputStr,',') SS ON A.id = SS.[value];
```

If that is still slow, I would suggest you are missing an index on `id`. Considering it is the id, then you'll likely want it to be clustered, and probably the primary key:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Addresses ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Addresses PRIMARY KEY (id) CLUSTERED;
```

Comment: I believe that the optimizer is too smart to run the `string_split` for every row if it's in the `where` clause. Tests I've made before shown the same execution plan  for `in` and `inner join` queries on multiple scenarios, I don't think this one would be different.

Comment: I agree, it should be smart enough, @ZoharPeled, and my experience has agreed with that; which makes me think it's more likely a lack of indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
DECLARE @inputStr VARCHAR(MAX) = '234,2344,12,523,5667,9825,345'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEST;

CREATE TABLE #TEST
(
    [value] INT
);

INSERT INTO #TEST ([value])
SELECT value
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@inputStr, ',')

SELECT
    surname,
    firstname
FROM Addresses A
INNER JOIN #TEST B
    ON A.id  = b.value
```